# Solving a fourth order non linear differential equation for explaining motion of a sausage in hot water.

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, graphing-functions, nonlinear-system

I am modelling the nonlinear behaviour of a sausage in hot water. I am trying to explain it's rotational, vibrational and translational motion in water with salt and subject to varying temperatures. I got the following equation. How do I solve the following equation analytically?
$$x^2\frac{∂^4x}{∂y^4}+\frac32\frac{∂^2x}{∂y^2}+x\frac{∂x}{∂z}-\frac{Ax}{\frac{∂^3x}{∂z^3}}=B$$
Where $x=x(z,y)$ and $A$ and $B$ are constants. I would also appreciate if the graph is provided.
$$x(0)= {e^3}$$

Comment: My guess is that you are unlikely to find an analytical solution and must consider numerical methods instead. You could improve the question by adding what type of boundary conditions (if any) you have.

Comment: @knl Why do you guess that an analytical solution is unlikely? I have included the boundary condition. I am in need for an analytical solution only.

Comment: By the way, is the equation supposed to have a dependency on $y$? Currently it looks like a partial differential equation since the first and the second terms have derivatives with respect to $y$. Of course these terms are equal to zero if $x=x(z)$ only?

Comment: @knl Yeah my mistake, sorry.

Comment: Now I can answer your first question in the comments. Currently it is a nonlinear fourth-order partial differential equation. It is very rare that you find an analytical solution for any given partial differential equation. You can check literature, e.g. [Polyanin's book](https://www.crcpress.com/Handbook-of-Nonlinear-Partial-Differential-Equations-Second-Edition/Polyanin-Zaitsev/p/book/9781420087239), but usually you have to resort to numerical methods such as finite differences. These will of course also give you a graph of the solution if that's what you require.

Comment: @knl Do u know any other place I could find this book online? I can't spend £118 on that book.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/46788/discussion-between-naveen-balaji-and-knl).